# Excel VBA Error Runtime error 438 getting web page class content

Tags: vba, excel

Using Excel VBA I'm trying to get the contents of a specific class from a webpage.

This is the code:

```
sUrl = "https://www.example.com/"
Set oBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
oBrowser.navigate sUrl
With oBrowser
Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: Loop
End With
Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("classNew")
```

This code is creating the IE browser and navigating to the correct page.
However, I get the error:

[image]

On line:

```
Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("classNew")
```

Compiling the code doesn't produce any error.

Comment: You need to show the HTML you are attempting ot target and share a URL if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know the index number of the class element you want, or if its the only element with that class name try:

```
Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document.getElementsByClassName("classNew")(0)
```

You'll also need `.innerText`, `outerText`, `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` at the end  in order to convert the object into a string.

Comment: There are several classes with the same name. I need to iterate through all of them. Then, I get the innerHTML

Comment: What have you declared HTMLDoc as?

Comment: Dim HTMLDoc As Object